# Share Memory Manager between Application and Package

Tags: delphi, memory-management, package

This question is a follow up of this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309730/package-memory-management)

**How can I achieve that my application and my runtime package use the same memory manager?** I thought that this was the case by default but since I get strange access violations and invalid pointer exceptions, I inserted calls to `GetMemoryManagerState` just before entry to the runtime package and in the runtime package and the returned state seems to indicate that the package and the application use separate memory managers.

Before calling a method in the runtime package, there are 61 allocated medium blocks and after the call (at the beginning of the called method inside the package) there are 0 allocated medium blocks.

Do you happen to have an explanation for that? What do I have to do to make package and application share the memory manager? Any more complicated issues when using FastMM?

**EDIT** BTW, is there a better way to check if the same memory manager is used than comparing memory manager state? `TMemoryManager` turns out to be a record, so I can't compare adresses.

Comment: They do by default. What Delphi version are you using?

Comment: HOw do you load the packasge? Dynamically or not? Is the application compiled with "use runtime packages"?

Comment: I load them dynamcially with `LoadPackage`. I have "use runtime packages" disabled.

Comment: ...which seems to be the point where I am wrong. Turning this option on seems to solve the problem. So I guess the memory manager is shared only if RTL is used as a runtime package. Correct?

Comment: That's right, Smasher. The RTL package is where the memory manager lives. If you're not sharing the *System* unit et al, then you're not sharing the memory manager. Any program that uses runtime packages must have the "use runtime packages" option set. It's you choice *which* runtime packages are configured for use, but one of those packages must contain the memory manager, and all other packages used by the application must also require that package.

Comment: And if you don't use runtime packages you would still have the same problems that made you decide to use packages. You don't even need to make your plugins packages. They can still be dlls. You just need to have the shared code in runtime packages. Or at least the RTL and VCL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ldsandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160694/ldsandon) and [Rob Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy) I figured out that it is necessary to use runtime packages (at least for the RTL) in order for the application and the package to share memory managers.

Enabling "Use runtime packages" and adding "rtl" to the package list solved the problem. Thanks to you all for your help.

Answer (score 4):

A package uses the same RTL state as the main program. That is part of the definition of package.

Memorymanager inclusive.

Btw, my notes about packages are here: http://wiki.freepascal.org/packages

Currently FPC is still quite far away from this (mainly due to the need to implement this on umpteen OSes and architectures through an external linker). Also due to the larger number of FPC versions in roulation, I suspect it will be less useful than many people think (I don't expect Lazarus components to be ever distributed in something as binary only FPC equivalent of BPLs/.dcp combos)

Comment: Yes, assuming the program is built with runtime packages and references rtl in project options, and the package itself requires rtl.dcp. That's the case by default but it can be changed.

Comment: Interesting point TOndrej. Didn't know that was possible. Thanks

Comment: But @Tondrej, if you do all that, haven't you pretty much broken everything else in your program, too? I think Smasher has demonstrated exactly that.

Comment: @Rob, yes, very likely. But - with a bit of care - the possibility is there to "rebundle" Delphi units in your own packages and use them instead of the supplied rtl, vcl, etc. Perhaps useful in some corner cases, or if you want to use modified RTL/VCL units.

Comment: TOndrej: in how far does it being a package matter than compared to a normal DLL? Since neither program state, nor VMTs are shared.

Comment: Have a look at a bpl in Dependency Viewer, or tdump. A package exposes RTTI, interfaces, classes/VMTs of its contained units as exported functions. This is the mechanism the compiler/linker uses when you build with runtime packages and what makes the code shared in the host process.